# Windows update KB4487022 download and installing issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

I am having the below issue with an aging Windows Server 2008. Prior to this there have been no issues installing updates.

The 'problem' update is 2019-02 Preview of Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2008. KB4487022.

From Windows Update, I get the following :-
[image: Error from Windows Update screen]

From the Event Viewer (Application nad Services Logs, WindowsUpdate) I get an 'Event 31' with the text 'Windows Update Failed to download an update.'

---

What I know & have tried tried :-

- only the one update is offered, and it is optional.
- local WSUS is not in use.
- Other updates have installed correctly today. (Windows Defender definitions KB915597 ver 1.289.464.1)
- The server has internet connectivity.
- DNS Cache has been flushed
- Firewall and AV software have been disabled
- Rebooted server.
- Stopped WU and BITS service, cleared /SoftwareDistribution/Download folder and started services again.
- wuauclt /detectnow on admin cmd prompt. (created same error in Event Viewer as above)
- no relevant entries in Event Viewer under Applications or System Logs.

---

So far, searching on the error code, KB article and similar terms have not shown any useful results in google.

It's not critical as the update is optional, but I'd still like to know what is causing it. It suggests a networking issue, but given working netowrking and other updates being fine, I can't fathom this out.

**Can anyone suggest next steps, or a possible cause?**

---

Edit 1 -

As suggested by joeqwerty, i've downloaded the KB installer from the windows catalog. The download was fine, but the install failed with the same error code.

[image: Catalog download error]

---

Edit 2 CBS Log

I've searched the CBS log, and only found the following lines which relate to this KB.

```
2019-02-25 07:39:48, Info                  CSI    0000020f@2019/2/25:07:39:48.515 CSI Transaction @0x22d34b0 initialized for deployment engine {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} with flags 00000002 and client id [26]"TI5.30723293:1212092951:1/"

2019-02-25 07:39:48, Info                  CSI    00000210@2019/2/25:07:39:48.531 CSI Transaction @0x22d34b0 destroyed
```

I then did a further search for "0x22d34b0" in the log to see if there were any other entries, which came up negative.

I checked for Errors, and only found the following

```
23/02/2019 00:41 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: MediaServer in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
23/02/2019 00:41 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: MediaServer-WebAdmin in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
23/02/2019 00:41 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: MediaServer-LoggingAgent in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
23/02/2019 00:41 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: SIS in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
23/02/2019 00:41 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: ADFS-FederationService in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
23/02/2019 00:41 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: ADFS-FederationServiceProxy in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
23/02/2019 00:42 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: OnlineRevocationServices in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
23/02/2019 00:42 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: NetworkDeviceEnrollmentServices in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
23/02/2019 00:42 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: FailoverCluster-FullServer in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
23/02/2019 00:42 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: OnlineRevocationServicesManagementTools in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
23/02/2019 00:42 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: UDDIServicesDatabase in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:08 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: MediaServer in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:08 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: MediaServer-WebAdmin in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:08 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: MediaServer-LoggingAgent in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:08 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: SIS in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:08 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: ADFS-FederationService in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:08 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: ADFS-FederationServiceProxy in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:08 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: OnlineRevocationServices in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:08 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: NetworkDeviceEnrollmentServices in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:08 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: FailoverCluster-FullServer in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:09 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: OnlineRevocationServicesManagementTools in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
26/02/2019 01:09 Error CBS Failed to get internal update: UDDIServicesDatabase in Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.0.6001.18000. hr: 0x800f080c
```

---

Edit 3 windowsupdate.log

There are entries in this log that relate to the KB article... again it's the unknown error 0x80240003

```
2019-03-05  14:12:40:706     244    1248    DnldMgr ***********  DnldMgr: Copy update to cache [UpdateId = {44EAA446-DC1C-4EEA-B113-62E4B8A98B1A}.501]  ***********
2019-03-05  14:12:40:769     244    1248    DnldMgr Asking handler to generate non-range requests.
2019-03-05  14:12:40:769     244    1248    Handler Generating request for CBS update 44EAA446-DC1C-4EEA-B113-62E4B8A98B1A in sandbox C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\36c6c7d69e84094689fbc7cdb7067817_ctc
2019-03-05  14:12:40:769     244    1248    Handler Selecting self-contained because update does not have express payload.
2019-03-05  14:12:40:769     244    1248    Handler Selected payload type is ptSelfContained
2019-03-05  14:12:40:769     244    1248    Handler Detected download state is dsStart
2019-03-05  14:12:40:769     244    1248    Handler Adding Windows6.0-KB4487022-x64.cab (entire file) to request list.
2019-03-05  14:12:40:769     244    1248    Handler Request generation for CBS update complete with hr=0x0 and pfResetSandbox=0 
2019-03-05  14:12:40:769     244    1248    DnldMgr   * WARNING: Copy update to cache failed with exit code = 0x80240003
2019-03-05  14:12:40:769    1192    65c COMAPI  WARNING: ISusInternal::CopyUpdateToCache2 failed, hr=80240003
2019-03-05  14:12:40:784    1192    65c COMAPI  -----------  COMAPI: IUpdateServiceManager::RemoveService  -----------
2019-03-05  14:12:41:580     244    1248    Agent   WARNING: WU client fails CClientCallRecorder::RemoveService with error 0x80248014
2019-03-05  14:12:41:580    1192    65c COMAPI  WARNING: ISusInternal::RemoveService failed, hr=8024801
```

I'm not sure the message is connected but there is also reference to this error 0x80248014. Googling gives this link :-

[New link for fix](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/all/error-code-0x80248014-while-trying-to-upgrade/4ac3c200-0c4b-42ee-b4fb-8626b5e8c91e?auth=1)

<del>I'm going to follow the instructions, as they go a bit further than what I've already tried.</del>

the new instructions didn't work. Windows update and the catalog down both provide the same error.

Comment: Try downloading the update from the Microsoft Catalog and installing it.

Comment: Trying that now, but i'd like to resolve this issue, if anyone has anything further

Comment: @joeqwerty :- catalog download hasn't worked. Same error.

Comment: Perhaps `c:\windows\logs\cbs\cbs.log` will contain more specific information about the error?

Comment: Take a look at the Windows Update log as well.

Comment: @joeqwerty : do you mean the one in EventViewer, application and service logs?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'll check the CBS log today

Comment: @Stese, there is a WindowsUpdate.log file in the root of C:\Windows. That may give you some clue as to why the update is failing.

Comment: Checked that and followed it through. No luck really.

Comment: Do you have enough free disk space on the C drive?  Anything under 10GB free is pushing your luck when it comes to installing updates.  Failing that, you might try Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) and look to see what happens around the time you see the 0x80240003 error in WindowsUpdate.log.

Comment: 90Gb free on a 160gb drive... so not that. I'll have a look at ProcMon and see if it sheds any light on it...

Comment: @Stese - Can you confirm that following services are running properly: Windows Update, BITS, Windows Modules Installer, Cryptographic Services?

Comment: Thanks for the followup. Apologies to all on, as I'd not updated. KB4489880 installed, KB4487042 is no longer available. I guess that is problem 'solved'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on one of my Server 2008 R1 machines, and was watching this question too but didn't have enough rep to comment my progress.

It looks like that update has now been superseded by KB4489880, which installs without issue. My guess is that it was a problem with the update rather than the server.

As for why the error code that was generated in the first place, the closest I could get to an answer was that the error code meant that the update was for a different operating system, but that was on another forum and I couldn't verify if that was true.